# How to place a div on top of another div, where all the divs are dynamically created

Tags: html, css

In this example, the box #1 is created first, then #2, #3, #4.

[image: Sample page]

When the number of boxes exceed the parent width, the folllowing box (#5) must go to the next line, but I want to place it in previous line as shown in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS3 `flexbox` module with direction set to `row-reverse` and wrap set to `wrap-reverse`

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYMEGE

---

Markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse; 
}

.container div {
  width: 23%;
  margin: .99%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #d8d9e2;
}
```

Comment: if it helped you can mark it as accepted. Mind the browser support and the differences between old and new syntax of flexboxes

Comment: yup, yet to check it around in some versions, working in ff, safari & chrome.